# MySQL Server - Puppet Labs module and Oracle Linux 7

Tags: mysql, puppet, percona

With the popular [MySQL server module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql) from Puppet Labs, it sets `$provider` to mariadb on Oracle Linux 7.x, which causes issues if I am not using Maria, but instead using Percona. The issue is in `params.pp`. I was wondering if there is a way to force the `$provider` to be mysql. I could try creating a symlink to `mariadb.log`, to get around this issue but it is ugly...

Here's the code from `params.pp`:

```
case $::osfamily {
'RedHat': {
  case $::operatingsystem {
    'Fedora': {
      if versioncmp($::operatingsystemrelease, '19') >= 0 or $::operatingsystemrelease == 'Rawhide' {
        $provider = 'mariadb'
      } else {
        $provider = 'mysql'
      }
    }
    /^(RedHat|CentOS|Scientific|OracleLinux)$/: {
      if versioncmp($::operatingsystemmajrelease, '7') >= 0 {
        $provider = 'mariadb'
      } else {
        $provider = 'mysql'
      }
    }
    default: {
      $provider = 'mysql'
    }
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql/blob/master/manifests/params.pp

```
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log at /[redacted]/modules/mysql/manifests/server/installdb.pp:25
```

Bsically, I am looking for a graceful workaround via Puppet over rides. But not experienced enough to know how to implement it. :(

Thanks!

Comment: There are no overrides for class parameters like there can be for resource parameters. Much less for class variables that are not parameters.

Answer (score -1):

<s>That you are trying to work through a provider suggests that you are approaching this through resources, such as `mysql::db`, but that's never going to work if the server is not configured to match.</s>  The `$provider` variable you highlight in the question is both set and used only inside class `mysql::params`, and only for certain OS families even there.  It is an ordinary variable belonging to the class, not a class parameter, and, being undocumented, it should be considered private to that class.  In any event, no, Puppet provides no way to override that variable's value without modifying the module.

It is class `mysql::server` that provides the avenue for configuring for an alternative MySQL fork.  It offers [numerous parameters](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#mysqlserver) by which you can configure all the details, but no once-for-all mechanism for setting a different MySQL personality. <s>I *think* you will find that if you do that correctly then all the resource types will just work.  In any case, you should not be declaring any resources of private resource types, nor overriding the properties of resources you do not declare.</s>

An example covering almost the exact use case you've asked about is presented in the module docs as [Install Percona Server on CentOS](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql#install-percona-server-on-centos).  Note that I have replicated the heading from the docs, but the word "Install" in it is a bit misleading.  That should not only *install* the server, but set the stage for all the module's resource types to *manage* it.

I gather that you would prefer a simpler way to configure for a non-default fork, but the module does not presently offer one.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly. Issue is that I am indeed attempting to use mysql::server with percona packages, on an Oracle Linux 7.x machine sets the $provider to MariaDB, which sets defaults for maria, such as the log file, etc. This causes the module to fail as persona's branched off of mysql so there are no MariaDB artifacts/files to be found, This seems like a bug to me. If the package and service_name are Percona-XtraDB-Cluster and mysql, then the same default should be based off of these parameters that I do provide.

Comment: @farhany, I have updated the answer to clarify that the *only* way the module presently provides for achieving the configuration you want is via class `mysql::server` and its parameters.  If you are not satisfied with the details then the module's code is available for you to modify as you like, and I'm sure Puppet, Inc. would be happy to consider incorporating any improvements you might choose to offer back to them.

Comment: I will indeed fork it and modify the code to achieve an over ride by basing on what server_name is presented to the public class. This seems clean to me, and in my testing is working as expected. I thank you for your input.